# biblatex: place article title at the end

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I am using `biblatex` and the bbx file: [`chem-angew.bbx`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/chem-angew.bbx) from the [`biblatex-chem`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/) package.
I want the bibliography to look just like the default, *but* the article title is supposed to be at the very end, after the pages.

Example:

> E. Schweizer, A. Hoffmann-Röder, J. A. Olsen, P. Seiler, U. Obst-Sander, B. Wagner, M. Kansy, D. W. Banner, F. Diederich, *Org. Biomol. Chem.* **2006**, *4*, 2364–2375. Multipolar Interactions in the D Pocket of Thrombin: Large Differences Between Tricyclic Imide and Lactam Inhibitors.

Please note, that there is a full stop after the pages. What do I have to change in the `.bbx` file to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to redeclare the `article` driver as the code to insert the title is directly in that part:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Diederich2006,
  author = {E. Schweizer and A. Hoffmann-R{\"{o}}der and J. A. Olsen and
     P. Seiler and U. Obst-Sander and B. Wagner and M. Kansy and
     D. W. Banner and F. Diederich},
  journaltitle = {Org. Biomol. Chem.},
  year = {2006},
  volume ={4},
  pages = {2364-2375},
  title = {Multipolar Interactions in the {D} Pocket of Thrombin:
    Large Differences Between Tricyclic Imide and Lactam Inhibitors}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

% Customisation
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  % Title inserted here
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I've also altered the formatting of the title so that there are no speech marks (as in your expected output in the question).

Comment: Thank you, but there seems to be a comma, not a full stop after the page numbers.

Comment: Nice, now everything works as expected, thanks again.